# SignalR save sender Id and receiver Id in ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr-hub

I am following this [Signal R tutorial from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc). I have already configured everything for SignalR to be working and it does work.

This is my Front End script to call SignalR

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.  
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
        chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
            // Add the message to the page. 
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name) 
                + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
        };
        // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
        $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
        // Set initial focus to message input box.  
        $('#message').focus();
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });
    // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
    function htmlEncode(value) {
        var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
        return encodedValue;
    }
</script>
```

As you can see in the microsoft tutorial, I require to create a hub class with this method.

```
public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
```

My question is, given an mvc application with login (each user have its own Id), how can I send the receiver Id to my backend so I can save it into my database?

I have already tried to modify the Send function

```
  public class chat
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid receiverId { get; set; }
}

   public void Send(string name, string message,string receiverId)
    {
        // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
        chatultimo chat = new chatultimo();
        chat.Name = name;
        chat.Message = message;
        chat.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        _dbContext.chatultimo.Add(chat);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }


I also made a modification in my function in the front end
chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message)
```

you can see that the Send function is being called in the front end, but after modifying the send function my application is not hiting the backend.

```
chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message,receiverId)
```

Another thing is I do not think it is a good idea to modify the send function. I think it is much better to  do the database job in the  $.connection.hub.start().done(function () ...

to make sure it is only executed after the handshake.

Comment: If you your send function expects 3 parameters you want to pass three arguments...

Comment: You'll find all info you need in the tutorial.
Check this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

Comment: @ev vk, Has your problem been solved?If Not solved! Please connect to me I am solving your problem.

Comment: @TanvirArjel thanks! I am already trying to fix it

Comment: @evvk Okay try your best to solve! If you cannot then knock me here.

Comment: @TanvirArjel thank you very much. In case I can not solve it. How can I reach you? I am quite new here...

Comment: @evvk Comment here! Then I shall tell you.